# Continuous For Each Loop Will not stop inserting into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a for each loop that will not stop inserting into sql server.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Google.Apis.Analytics.v3;
using Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace GooAnalyzer
{
    class Program
    {

        static void RunSecondSite()
        {
            var serviceAccountEmail = "543652534806-7lk19u13619g9pthghqger31sth9jpr4@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Key\key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
            {
                Scopes = new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics }
            }.FromCertificate(certificate));

            // Create the service.
            //Twistandtango
            var gas = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "GooAnalyzer",
            });

            var r = gas.Data.Ga.Get("ga:1860066", "2014-12-27", "2015-01-10", "ga:totalValue");

            //Specify some addition query parameters
            r.Dimensions = "ga:source,ga:medium,ga:campaign,ga:transactionId,ga:date";

            r.MaxResults = 100000000;

            //Execute and fetch the results of our query
            Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.Data.GaData d = r.Execute();

            foreach (var h in d.ColumnHeaders)
            {
                SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=UNDERGOD-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=GooAnalyzer;Integrated Security=True");
                sqlCon.Open();
                foreach (var row in d.Rows)
                {

                    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd1 = new SqlCommand { CommandText = "INSERT INTO [GooData] ([Website], [gasource], [gamedium], [gacampaign], [gatransactionid], [gadate], [gatotalvalue], [Timeinserted]) VALUES (@Website, @gasource, @gamedium, @gacampaign, @gatransactionid, @gadate, @gatotalvalue, @Timeinserted)", Connection = sqlCon })
                    {
                        sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Website", "4wheelparts.com");
                        sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gasource", row[0]);
                        sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gamedium", row[1]);
                        sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gacampaign", row[2]);
                        sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gatransactionid", row[3]);
                        sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gadate", row[4]);
                        sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gatotalvalue", row[5]);
                        sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Timeinserted", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"));
                        sqlCmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }

                }
                sqlCon.Close();
            }
        }



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var serviceAccountEmail = "543652534806-7lk19u13619g9pthghqger31sth9jpr4@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Key\key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
            {
                Scopes = new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics }
            }.FromCertificate(certificate));

            // Create the service.
            //Twistandtango
            var gas = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "GooAnalyzer",
            });

            var r = gas.Data.Ga.Get("ga:1381000", "2014-12-27", "2015-01-10", "ga:totalValue");

            //Specify some addition query parameters
            r.Dimensions = "ga:source,ga:medium,ga:campaign,ga:transactionId,ga:date";

            r.MaxResults = 100000000;

            //Execute and fetch the results of our query
            Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.Data.GaData d = r.Execute();

            Console.WriteLine("Starting...");

            foreach (var h in d.ColumnHeaders)
            {
                SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=UNDERGOD-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=GooAnalyzer;Integrated Security=True");
                sqlCon.Open();
                foreach (var row in d.Rows)
                {

                    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd1 = new SqlCommand { CommandText = "INSERT INTO [GooData] ([Website], [gasource], [gamedium], [gacampaign], [gatransactionid], [gadate], [gatotalvalue], [Timeinserted]) VALUES (@Website, @gasource, @gamedium, @gacampaign, @gatransactionid, @gadate, @gatotalvalue, @Timeinserted)", Connection = sqlCon })
                    {
                        sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Website", "4wd.com");
                        sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gasource", row[0]);
                        sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gamedium", row[1]);
                        sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gacampaign", row[2]);
                        sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gatransactionid", row[3]);
                        sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gadate", row[4]);
                        sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gatotalvalue", row[5]);
                        sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Timeinserted", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"));
                        sqlCmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }

                }
                sqlCon.Close();
                RunSecondSite(); 


            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code continues to loop when i run this:

> RunSecondSite();

It will keep on inserting and I do not know how to stop it or where to place the correct breaks.

I want to call more methods of this code in the console application later using the same for each loop as well.

Please advise.

Comment: Well, yes; it is doing all rows **for each column header**; if you have 200 rows and 10 column-headers, it is doing 2000 inserts; is that what you expected?

Comment: How do I fix this? It is inserting duplicates of data.

Comment: You are inserting all the rows in "d" each time you iterate over the column headers of the same table.

Comment: Please reduce the amount of code you have posted to only the code relevant to the question rather than dumping everything.

Comment: @Jerry out of curiosity, how many rows are there? if it is a significant number, this scenario lends itself to `SqlBulkCopy` quite nicely, which would be **significantly** faster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current logic is that you are adding each row to the database, each time you iterate over the column headers, resulting in identical rows being inserted.

From your code, it appears that "h" is never being used..

Simply remove:

```
foreach (var h in d.ColumnHeaders)
{
...
}
```

to become:

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=UNDERGOD-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=GooAnalyzer;Integrated Security=True");
sqlCon.Open();

foreach (var row in d.Rows)
{
    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd1 = new SqlCommand { CommandText = "INSERT INTO [GooData] ([Website], [gasource], [gamedium], [gacampaign], [gatransactionid], [gadate], [gatotalvalue], [Timeinserted]) VALUES (@Website, @gasource, @gamedium, @gacampaign, @gatransactionid, @gadate, @gatotalvalue, @Timeinserted)", Connection = sqlCon })
    {
         sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Website", "4wheelparts.com");
         sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gasource", row[0]);
         sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gamedium", row[1]);
         sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gacampaign", row[2]);
         sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gatransactionid", row[3]);
         sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gadate", row[4]);
         sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gatotalvalue", row[5]);
         sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Timeinserted", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"));
         sqlCmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
sqlCon.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply need to replace

```
foreach (var h in d.ColumnHeaders)
{
    SqlConnection sqlCon = ...
    sqlCon.Open();
    ... // snip
    sqlCon.Close();
}
```

with:

```
using(SqlConnection sqlCon = ...)
{
    sqlCon.Open();
    ... // snip
    sqlCon.Close();
}
```

Currently you are inserting all rows **separately and identically for every column-header**.

Comment: @JerryBust yes, simply that; in my edited example I've also added a `using` on the `sqlCon` usage, but the removal of the outer `foreach` is the key change.